# how can i get tag element by text content in beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have to scrap data from a thousand sites, local HTML files, the complication is that these sites are like 90's structure, almost same nested tables structure, no `id`'s no `CSS` classes only nested tables, how can I select a specific table base in the text in one tr tag.

`XPath` is not a solution because the sites are mainly the same structure, but not always have the same table order, so I'm looking for a way to extract those table data from all of them, selecting or searching certain table b some text in it and by that obtain the parent tag.

Any idea?

The code on every page is huge, here is an examaple of the structure, the data is not always on the same table position.

***Update:***
thanks to alecxe i made this code

```
# coding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

html_content = """
<body>
 <table id="gotthistable">
     <tr>
         <table id="needthistable">
             <tr>
                 <td>text i'm searching</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>Some other text</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Other text</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>Some other text</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>

 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>Different table</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</body>
 """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "table" and "searching" in tag.text)
print table
```

the output of print table or soup var is the same:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <table id="needthistable">
            <tr>
                <td>text i'm searching</td>
            </tr>
    </tr>
.
.
.
```

but with this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "td" and "searching" in tag.text).parent.parent
print table
```

i got the output that i want:

```
<table id="needthistable">
    <tr>
        <td>text im searching</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some other text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but what if is not always on the same two parent elements? i mean if a got this ***td*** tag how can i get the table where it belong.

Comment: post html code and the output you want

Comment: Create a [mcve]. Edit your question.

Comment: thanks to @alecxe i made the code and updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `find()` with a [searching function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and check the `.text` of a table to contain the desired text:

```
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "table" and "part of text" in tag.text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <body>
...     <table>
...         <tr>
...             <td>This text has a part of text</td>
...         </tr>
...         <tr>
...             <td>Some other text</td>
...         </tr>
...     </table>
... 
...     <table>
...         <tr>
...             <td>Different table</td>
...         </tr>
...     </table>
... </body>
... 
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
>>> 
>>> table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "table" and "part of text" in tag.text)
>>> print(table)
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>This text has a part of text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Some other text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, i made up this:
    table = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "td" and "searching" in tag.text).parent.parent

but i don't want to hard code the two parent element to find the table, any idea?

Comment: @EnnyRodríguez wait, why would you go to `td` and then up if you can use the approach provided in the answer - get the `table` directly? Well, for your option, you can use `.find_parent("table")` if you will.

Comment: i don't know why, i'm a litle lost with bs4 in this case, but when i try your code in the answer with my html file it works only if a remove the first table in the html content, dont't know why.... if i don't remove the first table tag it returns all the html not the table it find... maybe the html file structure?

Comment: @EnnyRodríguez ah, right, this is because you've got the nested tables. You can improve your solution and get the `table` elements that don't have any other `table` children elements: `soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "table" and not tag.table and "searching" in tag.text)`.

Comment: i found the solution thanks to you it look like this:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
table = soup.table.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "table" and "Relación de Clientes" in tag.text)`

Comment: @EnnyRodríguez alright, glad we solved it. Please see if you can mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use BeautifulSoup [regex filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

> If you pass in a regular expression object, Beautiful Soup will filter
>   against that regular expression using its search() method.

Example:

```
soup.find_all(name='tr', text=re.compile('this is part or full text of tr'))
```